# Is "Socketed Thing That Should Not Be Of Razors" real or a bug?

Tags: diablo-iii

[image: Socketed thing that should not be of razors]

I can only assume that this items label has not been replaced as it's clearly a description of the item rather than a name I think.

So is this a real item or is it a bug / easter egg?

Comment: Should not be of razors, *and yet is*. C'mon, Thing, you had one job!

Comment: This is how all blue items are named. Only yellows have random names, and Legendaries of course are specifically named.

Comment: @corsiKa Blizzard game designers had a little fun :P

Comment: I've primarily been playing the WD and this item drops very often. At some point I had enough, and then this happened:

http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/10700680844

Answer (score 68, accepted):

[It's a real item](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/thing-that-should-not-be); the base item is the "Thing That Should Not Be"; that is, something that's unnatural or shouldn't exist in this world. Seems appropriate for a Witch Doctor.

If it helps, the name of your particular item can be parsed as:

- Socketed (prefix; adds a socket)
- Thing That Should Not Be (base name)
- Of Razors (suffix; adds thorns property)

Comment: And hilarity does then ensue.

Comment: What a brilliant naming convention!

Comment: Some wonderful and hilarous names get built around the Thing That Should Not Be base :)

Comment: Link in answer is dead.

Answer (score 4):

That looks real to me. I've never played a witch doctor, but occasionally witch doctor items drop, and they generally have crazy names like this one.